# Absolute value in sequence proof

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

That's very basic question, but I want to know how to approach such problem because it's unclear to me - In sequence limit proof (Epsilon N) in case like this
$$\left|\frac{6}{3-n}\right|<\varepsilon$$
term on the left isn't always positive so we have to look at expanded inequality,
but then (I checked) we get these two inequalities:
$$n < 3+\frac{6}{\varepsilon}  $$
$$n<3-\frac{6}{\varepsilon}$$
Can someone explain to me what do we do with $N_\varepsilon$ and maybe I'm wrong with operations?

Comment: Do you want to prove that the sequence $\frac{6}{3-n}$ for $n = 4, 5, 6, \ldots$ converges to $0$?

Comment: No no I got there by estimating inequalities from here: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n^3 -4n -1}{6n + 3n^2 - n^3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you look for the limit, you should assume that your integer $ n$ is great. 
so, $$|3-n|=-(3-n)=n-3$$

and
the condition $$|\frac{6}{3-n}|<\epsilon$$ becomes
$$\frac{6}{n-3}<\epsilon$$
or
$$n>3+\frac{6}{\epsilon}$$

So, you can take
$$N = \lfloor \frac{6}{\epsilon}\rfloor +4$$